# What's a Hengeyokai's 'natural form'?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, races, shapeshifting

With the [humanoid (shapechanger)](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Shapechanger_Subtype) type, I believe their natural form would be either the Human form or the Hybrid form, but there are reasonable arguments to be made for either option. Is there a rule that states which form would be the 'natural form'?

Answer (score 1):

### For 3.5 there is no strict answer

Originally in Oriental Adventures' description, Hengeyokai's natural form was the animal.

> Hengeyokai are intelligent, **shapechanging animals**, able to shift freely between human and animal forms, as well as a bipedal, animalistic form. Several subraces exist, defined by the kind of animal form they can assume. They are typically found on the fringes of human-settled lands, where they can mingle in human form but retreat to solitude when they desire. Hengeyokai are not found in Rokugan.

Even their human forms somehow resemble the animals, they are.

> In human form, hengeyokai look exactly like normal humans, though (like lycanthropes) they often display some feature associated with their animal form. For example, a sparrow hengeyokai might have a sharply pointed nose, while a rat hengeyokai might have beady eyes and a long mustache.

Because the type of shapechanger has been removed in edition 3.5, there were some major changes. In the issue number 318 of the Dragon Magazine, updated statistics of creatures from OA were prestented. The Hengeyokai's type has been changed to Humanoid (Shapechanger). Their description hasn't been changed. Because of it the most probable option is that their natural form would still be an animal.

## But it is a humanoid type, so it's natural form should be a humanoid, right?

Unfortunately no. There is a great example of this case in the Fiend Folio. The Selkie is a humanoid (shapechanger), who has no natural form. They appear as humanoids when on land and seals in the sea.

Comment: Creatures with alternate forms retain a lot of things from their natural form, including saves and healthpool. Since the cat-form has many fixed stats, it wouldn't seem logical to have the cat-form be the natural form.

Comment: @Joninean Many things don't seem logical in D&d 3.5

Comment: @Joninean Furthermore, I don't know where you got the part about retaining the animal stats.

Comment: http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm "The creature retains its hitpoints and save bonuses [...]." This would mean that regardless of your constitution modifier, you would gain hitpoints as if you had the constitution score of your animal form, which is decent for dogs and badgers, but choose any other animal and your HP pool will suffer greatly.

Comment: @Joninean I suggest you'd read the Oriental Adventures book a few times more.

Comment: Implying? I've read the relevant text and the errata numerous times, and this is my conclusion. The ability functions like an alternate form, instead of "Polymorph Other", as of 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see any RAW that states which "should be" the natural form, what I do see is that each entry usually states what the natural form is within the entries description.

For Example:
Barghest: "In its natural form, it resembles a goblin–wolf hybrid with terrible jaws and sharp claws."

Aranea: "In its natural form, an aranea resembles a big spider, with a humpbacked body a little bigger than a human torso."

In the original Oriental Adventures, the Hengeyokai were not considered humanoid, which would lead one to believe the natural form is the animal form or hybrid form, which more closely mimics the Japanese myth's they are based off of, but that was changed in 3.5 back to Humanoid(Shapechanger).

As a general observation, it seems the natural form refers back to whatever the creatures "Type" is in the monster stat block

Comment: In the original OA, they were type Animal (Shapeshifter), which is closer to the original Japanese mythology. However, this caused mechanical difficulties (immune to charm, etc) and level adjustment, so in order to reduce said challenges, they changed the type to Humanoid (Shapeshifter). Based on the fluff text, they normally live as villagers, so chances are the natural form would now be considered the human one. I don't think there are any firm declarations on it, though.